# jQuery + MVC3 : Return ID of images populated through controller action

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using .net mvc 3 to develop web app.
Currently I got a view page which i generate a list of images through my controller action method:

```
public string GetContainersImg()
    {
        string output = "";

        var containersImg = dbEntities.ContainerTypes.GroupBy(t => t.ContainerTypeName).ToList();

        foreach (var item in containersImg)
        {

            foreach (var img in item)
            {
                output += "<div class=\"image\"><img id=\"" + img.ContainerImgName + "\" src=\"" + img.ContainerImg + "\"/></div>";
            }
            output += "<br />";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I want to retrieve the id of my image at my view, but i realise that using the jQuery command: `var id = ui.draggable.attr('id');` do not return me the ID. i wonder is it because my html is generated from controller action.

Anyone can help???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the mistake i made. ui-draggable here is refer to the  but not the image. Got it by calling ui.draggable.children() . I not sure is it a bad way though